# Migration from Apache James 2.3.2 to 3.4.0

Tags: java, smtp, james

We have an application that uses Apache James 2.3.2, which is an older but stable version. We plan to migrate to the latest Apache James 3.4.0 and we have been going through the documentation for the same.

On this [page](https://james.apache.org/server/index.html), we see a note that says:

> Apache James Server 3.4.0 represents the leading edge of development. **This code stream has many more features than the 2.3 code, but is not be as well tested in production.** Reasonable configuration compatibility has been retained with 2.3.2.

The above statement was a bit concerning, and we are unsure whether to migrate or stay on version 2.3.2.

What would be the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I have learned that the recommended approach would be to upgrade to James 3.4.0.